# phpscheduleit / booked - Unknown error in windows

Tags: php, phpscheduleit

I am trying to deploy the Phpscheduleit(http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpscheduleit/) open source software on my laptop (for testing) On Windows 10, Apache, mysql server.

The installation went on smooth and I am able to see the home page. But clicking on any of the link, the loading page shows up "Unknown error".

I have double checked the configurations on the config.php
Time zone matches with the laptop time zone, checked for user name password for connecting to the DB etc. All seems to be fine.

Does any one knows a fix for this ?

Is there any application log for this app ? I am unable to find any log directory.

Thanks,
S. Sudharsan

Answer (score 1):

Most typical problem here is properly setting $conf['settings']['script.url'].

Make sure it ends in /Web

For instance:

```
$conf['settings']['script.url'] = '//localhost/booked/Web';
```